# RDLC how to open a column containing xml string as a popup window?

Tags: xml, popup, rdlc

i'm pulling data from a table which stores xml into one of the column.
so far i know how to set it up so that i can [open the column as hyperlink popup](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/12/adding-a-hyperlink-in-a-client-report-definition-file-rdlc.aspx) but i'm still missing that gap on how to open it if the column contains xml data.

Or something like the xml visualizer that we see on debug mode in visual studio would be nice.
anybody can advice what's i'm missing or how to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

so after looking around, i can't find a good way to do this. thus i just use the most direct way of handling this problem.

i have the column opens a url which will pass the id and the type of error message and create a controller to show the xml.

```
public ContentResult Index(string type, int id)
        {
            //based on the id retrieve the error message xml
            string szXML = string.Empty;

            if (type == "mt")
            {
                sp_GetErrorTranByIDTableAdapter tableAdapter = new sp_GetErrorTranByIDTableAdapter();
                ErrorReportDS.sp_GetErrorTranByIDDataTable dt = new ErrorReportDS.sp_GetErrorTranByIDDataTable();
                tableAdapter.Fill(dt, id);

                //output that to the page
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0]["Error"] != null)
                {
                    szXML = dt.Rows[0]["Error"].ToString();
                }
            }


            return this.Content(szXML, "text/xml");
        }
```